# Perl 6 '^=' operator doesn't produce a result, causing program to never terminate

Tags: raku

When using the `^=` operator, the program never terminates and it doesn't produce a result. Am I doing something wrong?

To check that I could reproduce this I used this working, verifiable example:

```
my $k = 1;
$k ^= 24;
say $k;
```

As well as this, I even tried doing: `$k = $k ^ 24;` - but this still produces the same issue.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @melpomene to perform a binary XOR on `$k`

Comment: That would be [`+^`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_+^) as far as I can tell. [`^`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_^) seems to be something to do with [junctions](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several infix operators with `^` in them, all of them mean exclusive-or in some form.

- `^` Junctive xor, which is trueish if exactly one value is trueish. It is a value that can be passed around.

  ```perl6
  so     1 == 1 ^ 2; # True
  so     2 == 1 ^ 2; # True
  so    42 == 1 ^ 2; # False
  so 1 ^ 2 == 1 ^ 2; # False

  my $v = 1 ^ 2;
  so 1 == $v; # True
  ```

  I added `so` to collapse the junction, which you should do as soon as practical.
- `^^` Short circuiting xor. Returns the only truish value. If there is no truish value it returns the last value. If there is more than one trueish value it short circuits and returns `Nil`

  ```perl6
  say ( 0 ^^ 42 ^^ Nil );
  42

  say ( !say(1) ^^ !say(2) ^^ -1 but False );
  1
  2
  -1

  say ( say(1) ^^ say(2) ^^ say(3) );
  1
  2
  Nil
  ```
- `+^` Int bitwise xor. It compares the bits of two Ints and the value it returns has a `1` if exactly one of the Ints has a `1` in that position

  ```perl6
  say (0b10101010 +^ 0b10100000).base: 2; # 1010

  say 1.5 +^ 2; # 3
  ```
- `~^` String bitwise xor. Does the same as `+^` except on strings.

  ```perl6
  say 'aa' ~^ 'US'; # 42
  ```

Perl 5 used `^` for both `+^` and `~^` depending on what values it was given. Newer versions have separate operators for those if you opt-into using them.

---

The reason your code doesn't halt is that a Junction created with `^` keeps track of where the value came from.

```perl6
my $k = 1;
my $v = $k ^ 24;
say $v; # one(1, 24);

$k = 2;
say $v; # one(2, 24);
```

So then `$k ^= 24` creates a self-referential value. Which is fine, until you try to use, or print it.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @melpomene, I should be using the [infix `+^` operator](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/+$CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT#%28Operators%29_infix_+%5E), the *Integer bitwise* exclusive-OR operator.

Using the `<op>=` syntax for readability the solution is:

```
my $k = 1;
$k +^= 24;
say $k
```

A plain infix `^` operator is used for something else, unlike most other languages. Operators with `^` in them include:

- [Prefix `+^`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/+$CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT#%28Operators%29_prefix_+%5E) does Integer bitwise *negation*;
- [Infix `^^`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT$CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT) does a short-circuiting *boolean* exclusive-OR;
- [Prefix `^`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#prefix_%5E) is a range constructor;
- [Infix `^`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction) is a "one" junction constructor (this is what the code in my question was invoking).